# Weird Network Connectivity Issue in iOS9: iPhone 5 device

Tags: ios, performance, cocoa-touch, webview, network-connection

This is incredibly weird case that some of the users have reported, and I am able to reproduce this now.

Again, I am sorry there is no code to paste in this problem - it's a basic issue with a probably convoluted soution.

I have a few devices which are connected to WiFi, and they are all really fast - iPhone 6, 6 plus, iPad 3rd, 4th gen. However, my app's network api calls are super slow for iphone5, and ipod touch 4th gen.  They used to be fast, but I just installed the app, and a simple download of a 50kb image file takes more than 5 seconds. They are all running ios9.

**Update**:

1. I've turned off the devices and rebooted twice.
2. I've checked Developer - Network Conditioner and it's off.
3. I've tried other apps - they are all fast. It's related to only my app , although it's fine on other devices.
4. Again, I know there are so many reasons for this behavior without posting code - I might be purposely slowing things down or running something on main thread? 
   This used to work totally fine before. It's just something really messed up is happening now, and thats not related to any threading issues. It's just some kind of network mess up.

Anyone seen this? What is the best way to debug this?

**Update 2:**

I added a webview, and I am trying to load a simple web-page. That is super slow. I feel something's messed up on the networking level - just for my app on that device.

Comment: are you sure is not something related to the webservice? I mean, have you checked if the webservice answer fast to your requests?

Comment: @Signo What do you mean

Comment: you said "and a simple download of a 50kb image file takes more than 5 seconds." do you have webservices or you just download items? Have you tried with other connections (eg: 3g) instead of the WiFi on the slow devices?